# C++ и C# для игр

Tags: разработка-игр, 3d

сообщество stackoverflow. Начав изучение Java языка, интересуясь играми, мне бы хотелось узнать: почему для 3D игр, графики, в большинстве случаев используется язык C++ и C# ? Это связано с самим функционалом языка или с чем?

Почему на Java или других языках не пишут всякие варфейсы и танки?

Comment: Я могу ошибиться, но я не слышал, чтобы у JAVA была тесная интеграция с оптимизированными библиотеками ориентированными на конкретное железо, какая есть, допустим, между IPP и C++, . Боюсь, что сейчас Ваш вопрос объявят не по теме, как порождающий бесконечные дискуссии :).

Comment: Java - всего лишь пример. Но если в Java слабые библиотеки, то трехмерная графика пишется на C++ именно из-за библиотек?

Comment: На С++ пишется из-за скорости, тесного взаимодействия с железом практически на прямую, возможностей самих IDE для написания (например `UE`). С# в основном (unity) используют для создания игр под `android` - причина в простоте реализации и готовых инструментах.

Answer (score 3):

Одна из главных причин - производительность. Сравните, к примеру, Minecraft (написанный на Java) и Minetest (Написанный на C++). На слабом железе разница FPS в разы.